# figure environment can find file, but with figure* and subfigure it cannot be found

Tags: subfloats

I have a file containing the LaTeX code for a pgfplot picture in a subfolder of document.

The file is located at: `graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot.tex`.
When I create a figure like so;

```latex
\begin{figure}
\input{graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot}
\end{figure}
```

There is no problem what so ever.
But when I do this instead:

```latex
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}
\input{graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
```

Then I get the following error;

```
line 36.

! I can't find file `}'.
<to be read again> 
                   \@tempdima 
l.41   \input
             {graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot}
```

I am using IEEETran as the document class and this version of pdflatex: `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subfigure` -- you're using the `subcaption` package here, right? -- requires a mandatory argument, the width of the `subfigure` you're creating. Try

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\input{graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
```

and see if that fixes it.

**EDIT:** for the sake of completeness, since you indicated below you're actually using the older `subfigure` package, the syntax for that one is different; it has a `\subfigure` command but not a `subfigure` environment, and you'd use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Caption]{\input{graphics/graphs/dedup_ratio/visual/plot}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

That said, the package states, in its own [description on CTAN,](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), that "*[it]  is now considered obsolete: it was superseded by `subfig`, but users may find the more recent `subcaption` package more satisfactory*".

So yes, do use `subcaption` instead.

Comment: I am using this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure should I use subcaption instead?

Comment: but this did not fix the issue :)

Comment: I swapped to using the `subcaption` package and that solved the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `subfigure` declares itself deprecated and obsolete and notes that "it was superseded by subfig, but users may find the more recent subcaption package more satisfactory", so I'd say yes, use `subcaption`. And you're welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot will mark you answer as the solution, as soon as I am outside the restriction time limit :)